# IE 11 and Unable to get property PageRequestManager

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, internet-explorer-11

My site is not working on IE 10 and IE 11. Getting this error,

```
Unable to get property PageRequestManager
```

I have put `ie.browser` inside ~/App_Browsers folder. But still not working. I am using Telerik controls. I have tried this link http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After AppDomain(or Process) restart, it automatically started to work. I have only restart iis and putted the App_Browsers folder to server. But the formal way is https://bitbucket.org/shanselman/app_browsers.update,

```
You can update your entire machine's browser files.

1. Copy the files from the .\machines folder into \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers, overwriting your previous versions 
2. Open an elevated command prompt and run \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regbrowsers.exe -i 
3. Restart IIS (e.g., with iisreset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the content to the browser file will fix it but installing .Net 4.5 on the web server should also do the trick.